# PySpark dataframe - unable to compute max and min from a int column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am currently trying to fetch the max and min values from a timestamp difference's column within a PySpark DataFrame.

I've been able so far to compute the difference of timestamps between two rows (see [this link](https://www.arundhaj.com/blog/calculate-difference-with-previous-row-in-pyspark.html) for more details, it might be useful for some of us).

```
#The DataFrame tmp_df2 is as follow :
tmp_df2.show()

+----+---------+---+----------+--------------+---------+
|  id|    value|_c3| timestamp|prev_timestamp|time_diff|
+----+---------+---+----------+--------------+---------+
|7564|2.70412E7|  0|1498867200|          null|      NaN|
|7564|2.70412E7|  0|1498867800|    1498867200|    600.0|
|7564|2.70404E7|  0|1498868400|    1498867800|    600.0|
|7564|2.70405E7|  0|1498869000|    1498868400|    600.0|
|7564|2.70404E7|  0|1498869600|    1498869000|    600.0|
|7564|2.70403E7|  0|1498870200|    1498869600|    600.0|
|7564|2.70403E7|  0|1498870800|    1498870200|    600.0|

#Checking the column types gives the following result :
tmp_df2.dtypes

[('id', 'int'), ('value', 'double'), ('_c3', 'int'), ('timestamp', 
'int'), ('prev_timestamp', 'int'), ('time_diff', 'double')]
```

I am then trying to compute the min and max of the time_diff column using the following :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

tmp_max = F.max(tmp_df2.time_diff)
print(tmp_max)

Column<max(time_diff)> #I am expecting the actual max value instead

tmp_min = F.min(tmp_df2.time_diff) 
print(tmp_min)

Column<min(time_diff)> #I am expecting the actual min value instead
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated on the topic.

Thank you :)

```
# & Last but not least
spark.version
'2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292'
```

Comment: You can either show the value: `tmp_df2.select(F.max("time_diff")).show()` or collect the value into local memory: `tmp_max = tmp_df2.select(F.max("time_diff")).collect()`. The latter will return a list of `pyspark.sql.Row`s.

Comment: thank you @pault it is working fine. The latter is preferable for me as I'll reuse the values computed